# ASP.Net Core 2.1 - Is it possible to use DI inside of a custom JsonConverter class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I need to be able to get session object inside the `ReadJson()` and `WriteJson()` methods so that I can grab the current user's `TimeZoneInfo`from the session object and convert the DateTime appropriately... But I can't figure out how to access the `Session` object w/o dependency injection in ASP.Net Core 2.1

The `JsonConverter` class is selected by an attribute on the datetime properties of the entites that I want to provide this kind of conversion on like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ToLocalDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime TAdded { get; set; }
```

The problem is that Json.net constructs the instance, so How can I add DI to that class ?

OR access the `HttpContext.Session` object from inside this class ?

Thanks !

Comment: afaik that's not possible and imho it's the wrong place. The de/serialization process converts from/to json to/from your internal object structure - it's not about modifying values. Why not return UTC dates and let the consuming component (JavaScript?) let do the "display this in correct time zone" part?

Comment: Ideally it makes it easy to centralize the logic in one place instead of letting it bleed over into the Angular side of things where we would have to pass the TimeZoneInfo to accomplish this as this is a SAAS app that will have the tenants data in the company's time zone with employees logging in from other timezones... so I can't rely on the browser to localize ... This has been working well until we hit this DI issue when exploring what it will take to port the code to asp.net core...

Comment: Problem you are facing is good sign that you doing something wrong. Json converter responsibility is to deserialize data and it would be "big surprise" if data changes during deserialization. ASP.NET Core have "middleware" feature where you can introduce `TimeZoneMiddleware` where dates will be transformed into correct time zone.

Comment: I like the idea of using TimeZoneMiddleware to do this transformation...

Comment: @Fabio Another use-case is converting DB key's to and from hashes in the request/response pipeline, where those hashes have some runtime dependency, for example the hashes salt.